# StaleObjectStateException when using JSF Datatable with Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring, jsf, jsf-2, jpa-2.0

```
@Component
@Scope("view")
public class ProductPriceBean {

    @Autowired
    private ProductPriceDAO productPriceDAO;

    public void saveProductPrice(ProductPrice productPrice){
        productPrice=productPriceDAO.save(productPrice);
```

//the productPrice returns by the save action is the new object
        }

```
}
```

JSF:

```
<p:dataTable var="price" value="#{product.prices}" editable="true">
                    <p:ajax event="rowEdit"
                        listener="#{productPriceBean.saveProductPrice(price)}"
                        update=":form:messages" />



                    <p:column headerText="Price">
                        <p:cellEditor>
                            <f:facet name="output">
                                <h:outputText value="#{price.price}" >
                                <f:convertNumber type="currency" currencyCode="GBP"/>
                                </h:outputText>
                            </f:facet>
                            <f:facet name="input">
                                <p:inputText value="#{price.price}" >
                                  <f:convertNumber type="currency" currencyCode="GBP"/>
                                </p:inputText>
                            </f:facet>
                        </p:cellEditor>
                    </p:column>


            <p:rowEditor />  
        </p:column>  

</p:dataTable>
```

This works fine the first time...but the second time I receive a stale Product exception.
How can update the datatable with new Product?

Thxs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the trick:

```
public void saveProductPrice(ProductPrice productPrice){
    productPriceDAO.save(productPrice);
    product=productDAO.save(product);
}
```